# HandleRequirementAsync causes infinite loop in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, blazor, authorization, blazor-webassembly

I've got following authorization handler in my Blazor WebAssembly app:

```
public class MyAuthorizationHandler: AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    private readonly IMyAuthorizationService _myAuthorizationService ;

    public MyAuthorizationHandler(IMyAuthorizationService myAuthorizationService)
    {
        _myAuthorizationService = myAuthorizationService ;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement myRequirement)
    {
        var userIdClaim = context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).SingleOrDefault();
        if (userIdClaim == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var userIdFromClaims = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
        bool isAuthorized = await _myAuthorizationService.AuthorizeRequest(userIdFromClaims ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        isAuthorized ? context.Succeed(myRequirement) : context.Fail();
    }
}
```

It basically takes userId from claims and calls IMyAuthorizationRequest.AuthorizeRequest to check if user has permission. AuthorizeRequest is just an WebAPI call which retrieves whether user is authorized or not (boolean). It looks like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizationService: IMyAuthorizationService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyAuthorizationService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    public async Task<bool> AuthorizeRequest(int userId)
    {
        using var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/api/MyAuthorization?userId={userId}");
        await response.ThrowIfErrorReturnedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(json);
    }
```

In startup.cs, I added the policy "MyPOlicy" which has "MyRequirement" (an empty class inherited from IAuthorizationRequirement) for requirement:

```
builder.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", ()=> {
    return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddRequirements(new MyRequirement())
            .Build();
});
```

And I've injected MY and MyAuthorizationHandler into DI

```
builder.Services
   .AddScoped<IMyAuthorizationService, MyAuthorizationService>()
   .AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MyAuthorizationHandler>()
```

So, expected behaviour of this code is that if there's a page that uses "MyPolicy" like this:

```
@page "/specialPage"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
```

my WebAPI will decide with it's own rules if user can view the page or not.

However, the problem is that code above just keeps refreshing the page. The WebAPI (controller) gets called, it returns a valid output, lets say true, but when handler receives the value and calls `context.Succeed(myRequirement)` the page gets refreshed. And it does so in an infinite loop...

If i delete Authorize attribute from the page (basically turn off the authorization), my web page renders normally, without refreshing. Also if I delete API call from HandleRequirementAsync, web page is rendered normally without refreshing.

So, is it allowed to call a WebAPI from MyAuthorizationHandler or what am i missing here? Why this code keeps refreshing the page in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

I've been through you code, compared it with one of my setups and it all looks good.

Try this to prove the handler works correctly with async code:

```cs
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement myRequirement)
    {
        var userIdClaim = context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).SingleOrDefault();
        if (userIdClaim == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var userIdFromClaims = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        bool isAuthorized = true;
        isAuthorized ? context.Succeed(myRequirement) : context.Fail();
    }
```

And then try:

```cs
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement myRequirement)
    {
        var userIdClaim = context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).SingleOrDefault();
        if (userIdClaim == null)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }

        var userIdFromClaims = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);
        // lose the ConfigureAwait(false);
        bool isAuthorized = await _myAuthorizationService.AuthorizeRequest(userIdFromClaims);
        isAuthorized ? context.Succeed(myRequirement) : context.Fail();
    }
```

Comment: I swapped authorize call with `await Task.Delay(100)` and i tried to force the same thread context (lose ConfigureAwait(false)), both get stuck in infinite refreshing loop

Comment: OK.  This would indicate that there's something going on that you're not showing, but without a fuller view of your code, I'm stumped as to where to point you.